# Facebook crash after two log ins

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, facebook-login

I have made two methods for LogIn (Firebase) in my android application. One with email/password which works fine and a Facebook login which always crashes after 2 logins with facebook. I can't find out where is the problem, always after I clear cache memory at the 3rd time crashes. It doesn't matter how many times I logged in and out with email/pass always after 2 facebook logins crashes.

**Email/password login**

```
private void signIn() {

    String UserEmail = mEditUsername.getText().toString().trim();
    String UserPassword = mEditPassword.getText().toString().trim();

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(UserEmail)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter your username", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(UserPassword)) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter your password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }
    mSignInPDialog = new ProgressDialog(LogInActivity.this);
    setupPDialog(mSignInPDialog,"Loading...","Logging in");

    mFirebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(UserEmail, UserPassword)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        setLoggedIn("True");
                        mSignInPDialog.dismiss();
                        startActivity(new Intent(LogInActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                        Toast.makeText(LogInActivity.this, "Logged in succesfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        finish();
                    } else {
                        FirebaseException e = (FirebaseException) task.getException();
                        mSignInPDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(LogInActivity.this, "LogIn failed: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });


}
```

**Facebook login**

```
private void facebookLogin()
{

    mSignInPDialog = new ProgressDialog(LogInActivity.this);
    setupPDialog(mSignInPDialog,"Loading...","Getting data");
    LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(LogInActivity.this, Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email", "user_birthday", "user_friends"));
    LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(mCallbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            setLoggedIn("FacebookOnly");
            mSignInPDialog.dismiss();
            handleFacebookAccessToken(loginResult.getAccessToken());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Toast.makeText(LogInActivity.this,"Log in was canceled!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mSignInPDialog.dismiss();
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {
            Toast.makeText(LogInActivity.this,"Error" + error.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mSignInPDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
}

  private void handleFacebookAccessToken(AccessToken token) {
    mSignInFPDialog = new ProgressDialog(LogInActivity.this);
    setupPDialog(mSignInFPDialog,"Loading...","Logging in");
    AuthCredential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(token.getToken());
    mFirebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        FirebaseUser user = mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                        setLoggedIn("True");
                        mSignInFPDialog.dismiss();
                        startActivity(new Intent(LogInActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                        Toast.makeText(LogInActivity.this, "Logged in succesfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        finish();
                    } else {
                        FirebaseException e = (FirebaseException) task.getException();
                        LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
                        mSignInFPDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(LogInActivity.this, "LogIn failed: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

**Logout - MainActivity**

```
public void disconnectFromFacebook() {

    if (AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() == null) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"asdasdasd",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return; 
    }
    firebaseAuth.signOut();
    new GraphRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), "/me/permissions/", null, HttpMethod.DELETE, new GraphRequest
            .Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse graphResponse) {

            LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();

        }
    }).executeAsync();
}
```

**UPDATE v2**

**Crash-log**

```
E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
```

Comment: *`Facebook crash after two log ins`* Than where is your **`Crash-Log`**

Comment: Paste the stack-trace after the app crashes

Comment: @NileshRathod... can i ask something?

Comment: @HarshitSeksaria yes please

Comment: when I click on the log in button, only facebook's progress circle appears and nothing happens after

Comment: @NileshRathod.. How you done that thing *meet the best person on earth* in your profile? Please tell me..

Comment: @NileshRathod I added it, only that appears

Comment: @SűtőTamás... The crash-log you've uploaded is not relevant to any crash!

Comment: @HarshitSeksaria using this link **http://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=profile`**

Comment: @NileshRathod...Ohh... I got that.. you're a amazing programmer!

Comment: @HarshitSeksaria thanks

Comment: [crash-log](https://ibb.co/mUGR3c) only facebooks progress circle appears and nothing happens, but only after 2 log ins, before works fine what is very strange for me

Comment: should I upload anything ?